# Angular controllerAs and parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m actually creating a little directive and I m facing a problem with the scope object and controllAs.

In fact, I have this result :

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('historyConnection', function () {


  return {
    templateUrl: 'views/directives/historyconnection.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      idUser: '@iduser'
    },
    controller:function($scope){
      console.log(this.idUser); // gives undefined
      console.log($scope.idUser); // gives the good value
    },
    controllerAs:'history'
  };
});
```

From the html code :

```
<history-connection iduser="55"></history-connection>
```

I dont know how to make controllerAs work when passing parameters to directive. Can you help me ?

Important informations are commented in the javascript code above

Comment: I highly recommend you this post http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Comment: see this; http://jsfiddle.net/9ny4ujb5/

Comment: there are some explanations: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the scope properties to be bound to the controller you have to add `bindToController: true` to the directive definition.